# How do I change Foundation Zurb background?

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

I found out that html and body quote got basically a `background:none`.
How can i change that to apply a new background in one of my quote ?

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want a grey background for your body, put the following code :

```
body {
    background-color: #CCCCCC !important;
}
```

The `!important` lets you override a property that has been defined in another CSS. In the case of Foundation, the background has probably been set before.

Hope that it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to put the !important mark, and the background changed. However, i can't apply a background image in one of my <div> (because i have a top-bar so i want the background begin after the top-bar)

Comment: Here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/73hZY/
I put the @import "_override.scss" at the top of the app.scss

Answer (score 0):

You have two `background` tags in both style sheets of Foundation 4:

Try to edit:

**css/foudation.css**

```
body {
  background: white;
  ...
}
```

**css/normalize.css**

```
html{
  background: #fff;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I don't have any foundation.css . I have .scss files, and no body background is set...

Comment: Which files do you have in you version of Zurb Foundation?

Comment: I have _normalize.scss _settings.scss app.scss content.scss ie.scss print.scss screen.scss. All that files whitout a "_" generate a css file which has the same name

Comment: It turns my background into red but doesn't display my background image :/

Comment: It displays now the background, but the top-bar goes above it and the background doesn't scale all the screen

Comment: Put an external link of your site to see the type of problem.

Comment: I don't have any, i work in local, because i don't have any access at my work. Should i use only the CSS instead of the sass ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pwKym/ That's it. I didn't paste the framework css because one of them make like 9000 lines...

Comment: Step1:
Try to remove `background` and `background-color` from `html` and `body` from all your css files.
Step2:
Add `background` tags on one of your css file like `background: #000 url('your_image.png') no-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

If using foundation with SASS add this to ./scss/app.scss :

```
body, html {
  background-color: $white !important;
}
```

where $white - variable defined in ./scss/_settings.scss